# BeagleBone Black PM for 4.1?

Tags: beagleboneblack

For the past two years or so, I have been using the [bb-kernel from RobertCNelson](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/WL1835_Cape_on_BeagleBone_with_MainLine_Kernel_Debian_Filesystem) and recently was tasked with implementing Power Management features. After much investigation, I realized that the am335x-pm-firmware.bin was not being loaded at boot. Further, the kernel image does not include the CONFIG_WKUP_M3_IPC option and wkup_m3_ipc.c file.

Question is: Has anyone been able to get the PM working on the Beagle Debian kernel 4.1 version? If so, please inform me how to do it. Is there a patch somewhere to the kernel to easily implement?

Comment: I'd ditch 4.1 and go for latest mainline, or at least latest long term. Quite a few things still happened since 4.1 regarding AM335xx.